# Synonomize [ttf]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

[true-type-fonts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/true-type-fonts) has 42 questions.  [ttf](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ttf) has 4 questions, two of which are double-tagged with [true-type-fonts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/true-type-fonts).  I would simply clean this up to eliminate [ttf](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ttf) except that there may be value in retaining it. We may get some users with a "ttf" question who don't know what it means or don't think of the translation at tagging time.

Granted, [ttf](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ttf) hasn't gotten much use, but if we eliminate it, somebody may end up recreating it.  I suggest synonomizing it with [true-type-fonts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/true-type-fonts), instead.

Comment: -1 for not having a catchy or witty or punny title... +1 cause it's needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done. Makes perfect sense.

That said, someone really should write a tag wiki/excerpt for it ;)

Comment: OK, I can take a subtle hint.  Done.  :-)